# Why tap Gesture of Button get triggered even outside of its frame?

Tags: swiftui

I was testing accuracy of recognizing tap Gesture of a simple Button in SwiftUI, which I noticed it get activated even outside of its frame! I wanted be sure that I am not messing with label or other thing of Button, there for I build 2 different Buttons to find any improvement, but both of them get triggered in outside of given frame. I made a gif for showing issue.

gif:

[image]

code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Spacer()
        Button("tap me!") {
            print("you just tapped Button1!")
        }.font(Font.largeTitle.bold()).background(Color.red)
        
        Spacer()
        
        Button(action: {
            print("you just tapped Button2!")
        }, label: {
            Text("tap me!").font(Font.largeTitle.bold()).background(Color.red)
        })

        Spacer()
    }
}
```

**update:**

**someone said:**

*Do you see circle on click? - It is a size of active tap spot (kind of finger), and as you see, from your own demo, it overlaps red square - so gesture detected. That's it*

I made another gif to show it is completely wrong to thinking like that, in this gif, even with overlaps tap get not registered!

[image]

Comment: Do you see circle on click? - It is a size of active tap spot (kind of finger), and as you see, from your own demo, it overlaps red square - so gesture detected. That's it.

Comment: @Asperi: That's it? so easy? I do not think so! who set that circle? me? where is radius of that circle? how can I update that circle? by the way i can hide that circle from setting of video recording, it is just for showing the click or tap area.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.  People don't tap a button with a needle.  Your finger tip is 1 cm wide.

Comment: @ElTomato: why o why you are thing in this level bro? the issue is not that!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an answer why this happens other than maybe there is some built-in functionality that increases the tappable area where possible for a better user experience? Anyway, if you put another tappable button behind it or next to it, you'll notice that this no longer happens and the tappable area is exactly where you'd expect it. Therefore, I wouldn't worry about it. But if you need to clip the tap area to the exact frame, you could add a clear background to the button and add a tap event that doesn't doesn't do anything, but takes priority on that location.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        // Button behind button will take priority tap.
        ZStack {
            
            Button(action: {
                print("tap 2")
            }, label: {
                Text("tap me!")
                    .padding()
                    .font(Font.largeTitle.bold())
                    .background(Color.green)
            })

            Button(action: {
                print("tap 1")
            }, label: {
                Text("tap me!")
                    .font(Font.largeTitle.bold())
                    .background(Color.red)
            })
        }

        // Clear background with "fake" tap event
        Button(action: {
            print("tap 3")
        }, label: {
            Text("tap me!")
                .font(Font.largeTitle.bold())
                .background(Color.red)
        })
        .padding()
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.001).onTapGesture {
            //print("tap 4")
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: @ nicksarno: As you said I am agree with you about some built-in functionality that increases the tappable area where possible for a better user experience. If I wanted explain about my idea, it would be an un-access-able(for us) frame around the view and a little bigger than actual frame! But how I could access this frame or de-active this frame is my issue.

Comment: My answer explains why this is not a real issue and shows how to limit the tappable area exactly to the frame.

Comment: It is a real issue! I do not have to flip and flop my codes to get normal behaviour of codes.

Comment: When would this pose an issue? If anything, this is a good thing for developers because it improves user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a built-in functionality to expand the tappable area:

```
Color.red
    .frame(width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onEnded({ (value) in
        // Tap with Apple Pencil: location is exactly the frame
        // Tap with finger or an capacitance pen: the hit location is inaccurate
        print(value.startLocation)
    }))
```

Solution (Bug: If the view is inside a ScrollView, this will block scroll gesture):

```
let size = CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
Color.red
    .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onEnded({ (value) in
        print(value.startLocation)
        if value.startLocation.x >= 0 && value.startLocation.y >= 0 && value.startLocation.x <= size.width && value.startLocation.y <= size.height {
            print("inside frame")
            // action ...
        } else {
            print("outside frame")
        }
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved using clipped method . Below is the example .

```
    Button{
      //action 
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "barcode.viewfinder")
        .foregroundStyle(Color.agmColor())
}
.clipped().buttonStyle(.borderless)
```